# Toggle css style on click with .one function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle add/remove changes to the style of my page once a button is pressed using the **.one** function (following the example at http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FcvaD/83/) but my event doesn't seem to be firing, any idea what could be going wrong?

```
function handler1() {
    $("body").css("background-color","#000000");
    $(".ht").css("color","#fff");
    $(".fb, .sht").css("color","#ccc");
    var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    if ((filename == "j.html" || filename == "s.html")) {
        // TODO: add comment
        $("#logo").css("color","#fff");
    }
}
function handler2() {
    $("body, .ht, .fb, #logo").removeAttr('style');
}
$("#contrastIcon").one("click", handler2);
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L32p5Lge/

Comment: Could you add js fiddle link?

Comment: @AlexFilatov - question updated with JsFiddle link

Comment: the problem is that your elements don't have any `style` attribute in the beginning! put a `console.log` in the `handler2`function and see it working.

Comment: What do you expect, you're never running the `handler1` function, so there are no styles to remove, hence nothing happens when you click ?

Comment: @adeneo - thanks missed that out

Comment: where is handler1 execute?